# What is the strategic importance of cards that can draw a card?

Tags: hearthstone

Novice Engineer, Gnomish Inventor, some class-specific magic cards, etc.

There are cards that when drawn, can draw an additional card. Of course, having a healthy hand is important, but **how** important are they and on what types of strategies do they work well?

How much should I prioritize using these types of cards, and how much should I put in my deck?

A good answer would answer these sub-questions :

1. What deck types do they work with?
2. Given that I'm using a deck with these cards, how often should I use them?
3. What would be a good strategy to face enemies who have strategies who use this card type heavily?

Comment: @Chantola If I made a question about how important are cards that provide weapons, would that also be off-topic? I believe that these questions are answerable objectively. These are not "What card should I take" questions. These are "What is the strategical importance of these types of cards?" questions.

Comment: @Chantola Strategy questions and POB questions are not the same. This is a good subjective question although it would be an even better question if it was narrowed down a bit.

Comment: If you guys have recommendations to narrow down the question more while keeping the thought, feel free to do so. :)

Comment: Instead of asking how important they are (subjective), ask in what strategies are they most useful (objective because of established meta) or how to build a deck around them (objective because of established meta)

Comment: Cards that can draw cards are NOT ALWAYS 'important'. I have a very crazy and successful mill-druid deck that punishes greedy priests, warriors and warlocks very well. Just a further example of how any advice can be misleading depending on who you are playing.

Comment: Edited the question a bit, including the title. Let me know if it can be further improved. Thanks.

Comment: I think what you're referring to is a type of card called "cantrip", which is basically a card that replaces itself in terms of card advantage. This has the obvious benefit of not "using" a card to get an effect, but usually comes at a higher mana cost, hurting your tempo. Depending on your deck style, the additional mana cost can be entirely unimportant or devastating compared to the 1 card (dis-)advantage. In decks that play a long game and tend to reach fatigue, cantrips are worse because they reduce the deck size, in combo decks, they're better for the same reason.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, it depends on the deck type and your hero choice. Warlock's hero power has built in card draw that eliminates much of the need for card draw mechanics on cards. If you are playing a slower late game deck, you might be able to get away with slightly less card draw as your hand will be filling up naturally.

Card advantage is extremely important to win in Hearthstone. If you run out of cards, you are limited to playing only what you randomly draw that turn, rather than picking the best card from your hand. This severely limits your options to deal with your opponent.

Watch how many cards you play each turn, every turn. Each time you play more than one card in a turn, and only replace them with the single draw, you are losing card advantage. The more mana you have, the more cards you will be able to play each turn. Note which turn you run out of cards (or have nothing valid to play). Also note how many cards your opponents have on these same turns.

Then increase the amount of card draw in your deck until you can keep up with the pace of the game.

Finally, cards that perform an action/summon a creature and draw a single card (also referred to as card cycling) are not the only answer - more efficient card draw mechanics can come from cards such as Northshire Cleric, Gadgetzan Auctioneer, Acolyte of Pain, where more than one card can be drawn from a single card, increasing the value.

Comment: I find that I understand card-advantage's effect on strategy more from this useful guide about the [three competing resources](http://www.hearthpwn.com/forums/hearthstone-general/general-discussion/2916-the-three-competing-resources-tempo-card-advantage).

Comment: Bouncing a card back in the right situation can also be helpful (using a Brewmaster, for example).

Comment: @spudone yes, saving your own creature or bouncing back one with a beneficial battlecry can go a long way to preserving card advantage at the expense of a little tempo.